# Prevent users from pasting images into contenteditable-div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div, which is defined like this: `<div contenteditable="true" id="call-text-form-textarea"></div>` But I want to prevent the user, pasting images into it.

Is there a option, to prevent it with html? Or maybe I cloud JavaScript for this?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you could use an `input` instead?

Comment: @GuillaumeBrunerie I need a TextArea, with html content :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer to my question based on Karishma Shukla's answer and the following link:
[JavaScript get clipboard plain text...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60315089/javascript-get-clipboard-plain-text-with-enter-data-on-paste-event-cross-browse)

```
$("#call-text-form-textarea").bind("paste", function(e){
    var pastedData = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text');
    var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9@  `!@#$%^&*()_+\-=\[\]{};':"\\|,.<>\/?~]+$/;
    
    if (regex.test(pastedData) !== true) {
            e.preventDefault();
            setTimeout(function(){
                $("#inputText").html('');
            },100)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript.

```
document.getElementById('call-text-form-textarea').addEventListener('paste',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

https://codepen.io/karishmashukla/pen/NWMWZrY

Comment: Thank you for your help. But I still can paste images :(

Comment: @Jaro826 I am not sure why is that happening - worked when I tested :D
 I have added a sample Codepen link, please check.

Comment: oh.. My fault. I added it into a wrong function ^^. Thank you. I found a new option. Based on your answer and another.